# MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP using Classic ASP returns broken images

Tags: asp-classic, msxml, serverxmlhttp

I haven't used MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP in years and now i need to. When i use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to grab a page, the page returns with broken images. I remember doing this in the past, there was a line of code i would use and the images would resolve perfectly. It was sort of like setting the base url. Does anyone know what the code would be? Here's the code i'm using:

```
url = "notimportant.com"

Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objXML.Open "GET", URL, False
    objXML.Send()
    xmlResponse = objXML.responseText
Set objXML = Nothing
```

Comment: How are you getting the images. If  `xmlResponse` contains `img` tags then you need to look at the source and figure out what might be wrong with them.  NB I recommend using `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")` - it calls the most recent version of MSXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to place a `<base>` tag inside the `<head>` so that one line of code must be the following:

```vb
xmlResponse = Replace(objXML.responseText, "<head>", "<head><base href=""http://notimportant.com/"" />", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
```

Or as a more reliable way in case where the head tag is more complex and unpredictable like `<head class="head etc">`, you can use regular expressions to replace:

```vb
Dim Re
Set Re = New RegExp
    Re.IgnoreCase = True
    Re.Pattern = "<head[^>]*>"

xmlResponse = Re.Replace(objXML.responseText, "$&<base href=""http://notimportant.com/"" />")
```